# What does the W3C mean when talking about non-visual media in HTML Tables?

Tags: html, html-table, accessibility, w3c

What does this line mean, "Tables should not be used purely as a means to layout document content as this may present problems when rendering to non-visual media."? This is from the 6th paragraph [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.1).

More specifically, what do they mean by non-visual media?

Comment: @Pete - I understand they do not want to use tables for layout but what do they mean by non-visual media?

Comment: screen readers and braille machines for the blind and such things like that

Comment: I think that's the answer Pete.

Comment: Is there a way to mark elements as “not for non by visual media”?

Comment: Use the `aria-hidden` attribute https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-hidden_attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non visual media refers to things like screen readers or Braille displays for the visually impaired and other equipment like that

Answer (score 2):

“Non-visual” means anything that is not visual, i.e. based on what you see. Currently the most important non-visual mode of rendering is synthesized speech, either by dedicated speech-based browser or via assistive software attached to common browsers, for rendering content and possibly accepting commands via speech.

Next comes Braille display, which renders content as characters presented in Braille symbols to be read using fingertips. In principle, tactile (touch-based) presentation could also turn images to three-dimensional landscapes that can accessed by moving your fingers and hands over it.

Directly feeding data into the user’s brain via electromagnetic impulses is yet another possibility, studied a lot though probably not a common way of consuming web pages for some time.

In addition, non-visual rendering could use other senses, such as sense of smell, taste, cold, or pain. These would well be possible with the current state of the art, but it is difficult to see how they could be used as *the* mode of rendering, as opposite to being used as auxiliary.